# Component can't access action defined in test store (Vue Test Utils)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-test-utils

Following `Vue Test Utils`'s [docs](https://next.vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/v2/guide/vuex.html#a-simple-example) I created a test store (replicating my real store) in my test:

In it there's this action:

```
actions: {
  updatePowerSelectedAction(
    { commit }: ActionContext<State, RootState>,
    val: number
  ) {
    commit('UPDATE_POWER_SELECTED', val);
  },
},
```

... which the tested component calls when a button is clicked:

Template:

```
<button v-for="(power, i) in powers" :key="i" @click="comparePower(power)" />
```

JS:

```
function comparePower(val: string) {
  updatePowerSelectedAction(val);
  ...
}
```

I can see that the component is properly loaded, however it fails to call the action when a button is clicked via `await wrapper.findAll('.button')[0].trigger('click');`.

There's no error message, the action just isn't called. Why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `BattlePowers` add a class named `powerbutton` to make that buttons unique :

```
  <button
    v-for="(power, i) in powers" :key="i" 
    @click="comparePower(power)"
    class="button powerbutton"
  >
    {{ power }}
  </button>
```

then inside the test file `battle-powers.spec.ts` import the global store instead of creating new one inside the test file since this global store will be affected when you mock the button click :

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import BattlePowers from '@/views/battle/battle-powers.vue';
import store from '@/store'

describe('BattlePowers', () => {
  it('updates store variable powerSelected with power clicked by user', async () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(BattlePowers, {});
    await wrapper.findAll('.powerbutton')[1].trigger('click');
    expect(store.getters['powerSelected']).toBe("strength");
  });
});
```